# Create grouped by percentages in SQL, converting from pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by

I'm wondering how to compute counts and percentages for a particular data structure using SQL, having done it already using pandas.

Given the following example data:

```py
groups_1 = ["group_1", "group_2", "group_3"]
groups_2 = ["type_1", "type_2", "type_3", "type_4"]
N = len(groups_1) * 40
np.random.seed(1)
example_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_1": np.repeat(a=groups_1, repeats=N / len(groups_1)),
        "col_2": np.random.choice(a=groups_2, size=N),
    }
)
```

A sample of it:

```
       col_1   col_2
97   group_3  type_2
117  group_3  type_3
59   group_2  type_1
35   group_1  type_2
26   group_1  type_3
41   group_2  type_2
28   group_1  type_2
78   group_2  type_2
4    group_1  type_4
18   group_1  type_3
1    group_1  type_4
34   group_1  type_2
46   group_2  type_3
11   group_1  type_2
64   group_2  type_2
```

I can create counts and percentages using python & pandas as follows:

```
dt1 = (
    example_data.groupby(["col_1", "col_2"])
    .size()
    .rename("count", axis=0)
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by=["col_1", "col_2"])
)
dt1.join(
    dt1.groupby("col_1")["count"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()).mul(100).round(1))
    .rename("percentage")
)
```

which gives:

```
      col_1   col_2  count  percentage
0   group_1  type_1     12        30.0
1   group_1  type_2     10        25.0
2   group_1  type_3      9        22.5
3   group_1  type_4      9        22.5
4   group_2  type_1     10        25.0
5   group_2  type_2     15        37.5
6   group_2  type_3      6        15.0
7   group_2  type_4      9        22.5
8   group_3  type_1      8        20.0
9   group_3  type_2      7        17.5
10  group_3  type_3     10        25.0
11  group_3  type_4     15        37.5
```

How would this be done in SQL instead of pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same logic that you have used in pandas can be translated to SQL with the help of common table expressions and window functions. Here is how I would approach this problem in SQL

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        col_1, col_2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM 
        example_data
    GROUP BY
        col_1, col_2
)
SELECT
    *,
    ROUND(cnt * 100 / SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1), 1) AS percentage
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    col_1, col_2
```

Result

```
  col_1  col_2    cnt  percentage
group_1 type_1     12        30.0
group_1 type_2     10        25.0
group_1 type_3      9        22.5
group_1 type_4      9        22.5
group_2 type_1     10        25.0
group_2 type_2     15        37.5
group_2 type_3      6        15.0
group_2 type_4      9        22.5
group_3 type_1      8        20.0
group_3 type_2      7        17.5
group_3 type_3     10        25.0
group_3 type_4     15        37.5
```

Comment: @baxx Does this answered your question?